# Don't show a window for the removable devices

Tags: unity, nautilus, usb-drive, external-hdd

Every time I connect a removable device, a Nautilus window with its contents pops up. Can I disable it somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *System Settings*, then *Details*. Select *Removable Media* and tick *Never Prompt or start programs on media insertion*.

[image: Removable Media settings]

Comment: Thanks! I was sure that there was something but I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

Command line alternative:

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```